# Fancybox and Jcrop on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox, jcrop

Jcrop is working good with fancybox on all web browsers, except on Internet Explorer (IE). The cropping tools seems not moveable. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Fancybox code:

```
<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".various").fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '90%',
            height      : '90%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            afterClose : function() {
                location.reload();
                return;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
    }
</style>
<!-- -->
```

HTML/PHP code:

```
"<td align='center'><a class='various' data-fancybox-type='iframe' href='see-instalaciones.php?id=$record[id]'>[Actualizar]</a></td>".
```

Full crop.php code:

```
    <?php
$pageis = $_GET['pageis'];
$first = $_GET['first'];
$second = $_GET['second'];
$third = $_GET['third'];

// db class stuff
require("../../db/config.inc.php");
require("../../db/Database.class.php");

    $folder = '../../images/instalaciones/';
    $filename = $_GET['filename'];
    //$orig_w = 500;
    //$orig_h = $_GET['height'];
    $orig_w = 600;
    $orig_h = $_GET['height'];

    $targ_w = 241;
    $targ_h = 320;

    $ratio = $targ_w / $targ_h;

    if( isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder.$filename);

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w, $targ_h);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
        imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.'lg_'.$filename,100);

        imagedestroy($tmp);
        //imagedestroy($src);

        //echo "<p><a href='index.php'>Back</a></p>";
        //echo "<h1>Saved Lg image</h1><img src=\"$folder/lg_$filename\"/>";

        // get thumb image
        /*
        $targ_w = 115;
        $targ_h = 83;

        $tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w,$targ_h);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp1, $src, 0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

        imagejpeg($tmp1,$folder.'th_'.$filename,100);

        imagedestroy($tmp);*/
        imagedestroy($src);

        $iddb = $_GET["iddb"];
        $filenamedb = $_GET["filenamedb"];

        if ($filenamedb != $filename) {
          $db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);

          // connect to the server
          $db->connect();

          $data['filename'] = $filename;
          $db->query_update(TABLE_INSTA_GAL, $data, "id=$iddb");

          $db->close();

          // delete images
          $filenamedb_lg = "../../images/instalaciones/lg_$filenamedb";
          $filenamedb_th = "../../images/instalaciones/th_$filenamedb";
          $filenamedb = "../../images/instalaciones/$filenamedb";

          //imagedestroy($filenamedb);
          unlink($filenamedb_lg);
          unlink($filenamedb_th);
          unlink($filenamedb);

          //echo $filenamedb;



        }
        else {
          //echo ">>>>>>>> filename SAMA";
        }
        header("Location: crop-thumb.php?filename=$filename&height=$orig_h");
        //echo "<p><h3>Image is updated! <a href='javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();'>[x] close this window</a></h3></p>";
        //exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Using the JQuery JCrop Plugin, and PHP for Image Uploads</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                boxWidth: 500, boxHeight: 500,
                aspectRatio: <?php echo $ratio?>,
                setSelect: [0,0,<?php echo $orig_w.','.$orig_h;?>],
                onSelect: updateCoords,
                onChange: showCoords, 
                onRelease:  clearCoords,
                onChange: updateCoords
            });
        });

            function showCoords(c)
            {
                /*
                $('#x1').val(c.x);
                $('#y1').val(c.y);
                $('#x2').val(c.x2);
                $('#y2').val(c.y2);
                */
                $('#w').val(c.w);
                $('#h').val(c.h);
            };

            function clearCoords()
            {
                $('#coords input').val('');
            }; 

            function checkCoords()
            {
                if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
                alert('Please select a crop region then press submit.');
                return false;
            };

        function updateCoords(c)
        {
            //showPreview(c);
            $("#x").val(c.x);
            $("#y").val(c.y);
            $("#w").val(c.w);
            $("#h").val(c.h);
        }

        function showPreview(coords)
        {
            var rx = <?php echo $targ_w;?> / coords.w;
            var ry = <?php echo $targ_h;?> / coords.h;

            $("#preview img").css({
                width: Math.round(rx*<?php echo $orig_w;?>)+'px',
                height: Math.round(ry*<?php echo $orig_h;?>)+'px',
                marginLeft:'-'+  Math.round(rx*coords.x)+'px',
                marginTop: '-'+ Math.round(ry*coords.y)+'px'
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Move the selection on image and crop!</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="<?php echo $folder.$filename?>" id="cropbox" alt="cropbox" />

                </td>
                <!--<td>
                    Large img Preview:
                    <div id="preview">
                        <img src="<?php echo $folder.$filename?>" alt="thumb" />
                    </div>
                </td>-->
            </tr>
        </table>

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCoords();">
            <p>
                <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
            <!--<input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
            <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />-->
            <label>W <input type="text" size="4" id="w" name="w" /></label>
            <label>H <input type="text" size="4" id="h" name="h" /></label>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Crop Image!" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your document has a proper `DOCTYPE` ... personally I don't think is a fancybox issue : could you share a link?

Comment: I edited and included full crop code there.. I think there is DOCTYPE there

Comment: possible duplicate of [jCrop API is null or not an object in IE, but works in FF, Chrom, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210063/jcrop-api-is-null-or-not-an-object-in-ie-but-works-in-ff-chrom-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor syntax:

```
jcrop_api = $.Jcrop($('#preview, #source'), {});
```

rather than the callback syntax:

```
$('#source').Jcrop({
```

Then do the rest using `jcrop_api`.

**References**

- [TinyMCE - jQuery Plugin](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:jQuery_Plugin)
- [Which jQuery plugin design pattern should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127600/which-jquery-plugin-design-pattern-should-i-use)